# How can I get rid of spam users

Tags: plone, spam-prevention

The company I work for have a small Plone blog. But we have a problem with spam accounts. We use captcha on the site and Plone sends a mail to the users that they must confirm before they can edit the user profile. Still about 600 spam users are created every day. In the Plone user profile they paste all kinds of commercial links.

We are located in Denmark and the blog is in danish, therefore I have made a script to delete all users with a non danish mail adress. But even though most of the real users have a danish mail account I probably still deletes some real users when running the script.

The spam users register from a vide range of ip-adresses, so blocking ip's is not an option.

Does anyone have ideas to what to do about this problem?

Comment: Have you considered disabling links in the profiles?

Comment: Where are you getting the figure '600' from? And how many 'real' users join per day?

Comment: Have you analyzed the server logs to make sure the spammers are not somehow bypassing the captcha and email confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

Disable Plone comments/public user creation and use a third party commenting service such as Disqus.

Answer (score 0):

They somehow trick recaptcha (if you find out, please let me know :)

But how do they do the email validation? They don't have to. Plone **join_form** has a hidden field for **password** which is filled by this bot and Plone saves it as the real password (check the REQUEST object comming from this bot)

So the bot doesn't need to check email for password. That's how they get in and activate those accounts. So fix the hidden password field from join_form.

Then, remove all users that have links in their profile description (as a real user you don't do that, do you?). Also don't let the users to input HTML within their profile description.